# Android run Activity with WebView loading url in the background

Tags: android, android-webview, android-animation

I have an application that shows an animation when starting up (I'll call the activity LoadActivity). I call a new activity (I'll call it WebViewActivity) through an intent after waiting a few seconds (so the animation is fully displayed).

However this causes me to wait for the page to load after the animation is finished, which isn't very user friendly.

So I was wondering if there is any way to start my WebViewActivity in the background in the oncreate of the LoadActivity and at the onPageFinished event of the WebViewAcivity to finish the LoadActivity?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried to start with the WebViewActivity and from there go to the LoadActivity?

Comment: looks like a good idea, so I just start the WebViewActivity on starting up the application, start the LoadActivity with an Intent in my WebViewActivity's onCreate event. But then how do I close my LoadActivity and return to the WebViewActivity? I tried setting finish() after a certain timeout to finish LoadActivity but that just kills my entire application

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could do is try to cache the html page while you are in the loading activity. Then once the WebViewActivity loads you could try to load from the cache. This would be quicker then loading from the web. You would need a failsafe in case the page wasn't able to be cached in time. In that case the user would just have to wait for the page to load.